# Fancybox gallery with images in different places

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox, image-gallery

I have a (html) page with an image gallery (all images together) and one separate image.

I put all the images from the image gallery in a

```
<div id="imageGallery">
```

I put the separate image in a

```
<div id="separateImage">
```

and I have javascript

```
$('#imageGallery a').fancybox();
$('#separateImage a').fancybox();
```

Fancybox works fine on both, the image gallery and the separate image. I can cycle through the image gallery, however, the separate image is not part of the cycle. How can I make it so that it cycles through all the images: those from the image gallery and the separate image?

I tried adding

```
rel="gallery"
```

to the anchors as explained at https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-jquery-david-sawyer-mcfarland-2nd/chapter-7/advanced-gallery-with-jquery

but apparently this only works if all images are in the same div (id)!?

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are binding fancybox to two different selectors :

`$('#imageGallery a')` and `$('#separateImage a')` but in order to make a gallery, all elements whether they are within the same `div` or not, need to use the same selector (fancybox v2.x)

So without having to hard-code manually each element of each separated `div`, you could do :

```
$("#imageGallery a, #separateImage a")
    .addClass("fancybox")
    .attr("rel", "gallery")
    .fancybox({
       //API options
       padding: 8 // example
    });
```

Now all elements regardless their position share the same *class* and `rel` attribute.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JRxqh/)**